# concatenating String variables in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, string-concatenation

I have the following PowerShell script:

```
$Folder = Get-Location
$FileName = Get-Item *.csv | Select-Object Name
$FullPath = Get-Item *.csv | Select-Object FullName
$Archive = $Folder, "Archive" -join '\'
$FileArchive = $Archive, $FileName -join '\'
```

The output is as follows:

```
Path
C:\Test

Name : Orders_1408230845.csv

FullName : C:\Test\Orders_1408230845.csv

C:\Test\Archive
C:\Test\Archive\
```

The problem is that for `$FileArchive` I expect `C:\Test\Archive\Orders_1408230845.csv`, but it only shows `C:\Test\Archive\` (without the filename).
Why is the filename not added to `$Archive`?

I also tried other string concatenation, like `+` operator or the `Concat` method, but to no avail.

Comment: I expect that `$FileName.GetType()` will show that `$FileName` is not a `string`.

Comment: `Get-Item *.csv` could return many files so you need to process each with a For-EachObject loop - the short syntax would look like this: `| % { $_.FullName }`. `$_` will be the current object passed from `Get-Item`.  You can also use this syntax for concatenation `$FileArchive = "${$Folder}\Archive\${$_.Name}"`

Comment: What is it what you're actually trying to do? If you want to build a proper path you may use [Join-Path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/join-path?view=powershell-7.3) instead of quirky string acrobatics. ;-)

Comment: Juerg, try the following command. It will produce a fully qualifed path for each .csv file. `Get-Item -Path '*.csv' | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName` No string concatenation needed. If it were needed, `Join-Path` is the command to use. Is there more than one .csv file in the directory?

Comment: I've done it for this post, but please [format your posts properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) in the future.

Answer (score 2):

[`Select-Object`](https://docs.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object) (`select`) by default returns *a `[pscustomobject]` instance* that has the *requested properties* - even when you're only asking for a *single* property.

**What you're interested in are only the property *values***, which you can obtain by using the
**`-ExpandProperty`** parameter instead of the (possibly positionally implied) `-Property` parameter:

```bash
$FileName = Get-Item *.csv | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
$FullPath = Get-Item *.csv | Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName
```

Since you're collecting the results in memory anyway, a **simpler alternative is to use *property access***, which - thanks to [member-access enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Member-Access_Enumeration) - would even work if *multiple* files are returned:

```bash
$FileName = (Get-Item *.csv).Name
$FullPath = (Get-Item *.csv).FullName
```

Note:

- As [Mister Smith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4438168/mistersmith) points out, it's safer to process the results in a *loop*, given that your `Get-Item` call may return *multiple* files.
- Instead of using `-join '\'`, consider using the [`Join-Path`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/join-path) cmdlet.

---

As for **why the filename was missing**:

> `$Archive, $FileName -join '\'`

- As explained above, `$FileName` isn't a *string*, but a `[pscustomobject]` instance with a `.Name` property.
- Due to a long-standing *bug* - see [GitHub issue #6163](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/6163)  - such instances situationally stringify *to the empty string*, which is what you saw.

A simplified example; the bug is present in *Windows PowerShell*, as well as in [*PowerShell (Core)*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) up to at least v7.3.7 (current as of this writing):

```bash
# !! -> 'C:\temp\', i.e the custom object stringified to the empty string. 
'C:\temp', [pscustomobject] @{ Name = 'foo.csv' } -join '\'
```

(Curiously, `Join-Path 'C:\temp' ([pscustomobject] @{ Name = 'foo.csv' })` does *not* exhibit this problem - you'll get the usual, hashtable-*like* stringification.)